Rotate the app to landscape where app replies on sensors for rotation in mobile app automation
I am having mobile app which starts in portrait and then requires device to change orientation to landscape mode to continue. I was performing mobile automation on this app using appium 2 and appium-pythin-client 4.0.0. The app relies on the sensor to change the orientation. I used different methods provided by appium webdriver to do this action but it didn't help. When the code runs for example , driver.orientation = "LANDSCAPE" , this does not change the orientation of mobile app , but if I minimize the mobile app , the screen of the emulator device is turned to landscape. Is there any solution for this ? please help
Tried different methods provided by appium like driver.orientation = "LANDSCAPE" , tried shell command but nothing helped.
I am getting below error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Mobile_Automation\Test.py", line 159, in <module>
    d.orientation = "LANDSCAPE"
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Mobile_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 472, in orientation
    self.execute(Command.SET_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, {'orientation': value})
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Mobile_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\Mobile_Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 125, in check_response
    raise exception_class(msg=message, stacktrace=format_stacktrace(stacktrace))
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Screen rotation cannot be changed to ROTATION_270 after 2000ms. Is it locked programmatically?
Stacktrace:
io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Screen rotation cannot be changed to ROTATION_270 after 2000ms. Is it locked programmatically?
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.model.internal.CustomUiDevice.setRotationSync(CustomUiDevice.java:223)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.SetOrientation.safeHandle(SetOrientation.java:41)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:59)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:259)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:253)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)


I have run into a similar issue and found that putting it into the background and then into the foreground before setting the orientation helped.
See this page for more: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/troubleshooting/app-orientation-issues#python
